# How to install and use jedi-vim python IDE for vim on ubuntu

Tags: python, vim, ide

How to install jedi-vim python plugin on vim installed on ubuntu and use it's features from remote terminal window. I have gone through documentation as describe but my vim acts in the same normal was as it was before !

I tryied

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone git://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim.git
```

Answer (score 12):

Did you setup vim-addon-manager?

```
vim-addons status
vim-addons install python-jedi
vim-addons status
```

Answer (score 7):

Try with installing following packages in [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=jedi&searchon=names) :

```
sudo apt-get install vim-python-jedi
```

and then with your normal (non root) user:

```
vim-addons install python-jedi
```

Comment: I have downloaded it but still I cannot use it in vim. I can see no changes in vim. What should I do to my .vimrc file ?

Comment: did you download or install the package? you can simply install it with that command. Not need `git clone`.Sorry. I dont know how to use it.

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get install vim-python-jedi in terminal and installed it